# equal_range and std::unordered_multiset

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

My understanding is that we can't make any assumptions about the order of the elements within unordered... containers (even though they are implemented via hash tables). If that is correct, how can std::unordered_multiset::equal_range() return a range of equal values?

For instance:

```
typedef std::unordered_multiset<int> int_set;
typedef int_set::iterator int_set_iterator;

int_set set;
set.insert(1);
set.insert(2);
set.insert(1);
set.insert(3);
set.insert(1);

// equal_range seems to assume all 1s are located next to each other
std::pair<int_set_iterator, int_set_iterator> range = set.equal_range(1);

size_t range_size = std::distance(range.first, range.second); // the value is 3
```

Comment: you can think multiset as a set of arrays of equal elements, If I remember correctly that also is one of the possible implementations. (each array contains elements with same hash)

Comment: @DarioOO: Yes - I understand this is how it works in practice. But is there a Standard clause that would require it?

Comment: I can't grab the clause, but common C++ documentaion sites (cplusplus, cppreference) explicitly say that. See the answer.

Comment: before rejectin my answer se the edit wich include details about spec

Comment: @DarioOO: I didn't reject your answer - in fact I upvoted it, but I can pick only one answer as the accepted one and Columbo was the first to point to the actual standard. Your answer is good as well :)

Comment: Ah ok, because first you accepted my answer, then switched over his answer (wich also was inaccurate, he just edited now after reading my comments). :) I was just asking to change again (on metaoverflow they suggest doing that). So ok :) It's fine anyway for me and thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard specifies how equal elements lie in the range in [unord.req]/6:

> In containers that support equivalent keys, **elements with equivalent
>   keys are adjacent to each other in the iteration order of the
>   container**. Thus, although the absolute order of elements in an
>   unordered container is not specified, its elements are  grouped into
>   equivalent-key groups such that all elements of each group have
>   equivalent keys. Mutating operations on unordered containers shall
>   preserve the relative order of elements within each equivalent-key
>   group unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I get how the implementations would make it work. I am more interested in the Standard. If the Standard requires equal elements to be grouped together, is unordered_multiset a somewhat misleading name?

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic Obviously it is. It should be called `HashMultiset` or similar. There were numerous discussions about this misleading "unordered_*" terminology. :P

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic: My understanding is that the "unordered" containers were based on the STL's "hash" containers ([`hash_map`](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) etc.), but ended up sufficiently different that giving them the same name was considered too confusing; so we ended up with a differently confusing compromise.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes - I remember working with the old hash_ containers. I guess a name like "partially_unordered_multimap" wouldn't be ideal either, but "unordered" is simply misleading.

Comment: Elements are not sorted, and implementation forbids to do that by requiring that relative order has to be preserved (order in wich elements are added).. See my edited answer, you quoted right paragraph but read it more carefully @Columbo

Comment: and elements are not continuos -_-

Answer (score 5):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_multiset/)

> Elements with equivalent values are grouped together in the same bucket and in such a way that an iterator (see [equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/unordered_multiset::equal_range)) can iterate through all of them.

From standard:

> **unordered_multiset::equal_range**: The member function returns a range that contains all of  the  elements with the specified key. It returns make_pair(end(), end()) if no such elements exist

to understand see also equal_range:

> Thus, the function determines the largest range of positions over which val can be inserted  in  the sequence and still preserve  its ordering.

**There is no mandate about HOW this ordering is preserved**.

It is not specified anywhere that equal elements need to be contiguos if they have same key and value. Same key may mean that elements with same hash could be grouped togheter (equivalent means same hash), infact the following test provide a example in wich different elements are grouped by key (all have key 1 because of overrided hash_function), but the code is still working correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct my_hash
{
    size_t operator()(const T k) const
    {
    // Compute individual hash values for two data members and combine them using XOR and bit shifting
    return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    typedef std::unordered_multiset<int,my_hash<int> > int_set;
    typedef int_set::iterator int_set_iterator;

    int_set set;
    set.insert(1);
    set.insert(2);
    set.insert(1);
    set.insert(2);
    set.insert(3);
    set.insert(1);

    // equal_range seems to assume all 1s are located next to each other
    std::pair<int_set_iterator, int_set_iterator> range = set.equal_range(1);
    size_t range_size = std::distance(range.first, range.second);
    std::cout<<range_size<<std::endl; // print 3

    range = set.equal_range(2);
    range_size = std::distance(range.first, range.second);
    std::cout<<range_size<<std::endl; //print 2

    range = set.equal_range(3);
    range_size = std::distance(range.first, range.second);
    std::cout<<range_size<<std::endl; //print 1

    return 0;
}
```

In short words, equal_range on unordered_multiset, generate a "list" of values that are first selected by key (hash value), then, those values are "filtered" so that they are equivalent and (according to equal_range spec) ordered by  operator <=

This is all based on specifications, implementation still open.
Since the question is "HOW", a possible way would be

1. Take elements in the bucket with a given hash_code
2. start filtering elements discarding unneeded elements with operator <=

A smart implementation of the unordered_multiset would "pre_filter" in some way the elements so that calling "equal_range" is cheap. but a implementation's is not required to be so smart and could as well incurr a performance penality when calling "range_equals" (assuming you have a not very smart hash_function)

Comment: That's really the answer I am looking for. Can you reference the actual C++ Standard or at least the Stroustrup book? Many people don't consider cplusplus.com a good reference.

Comment: See [unord.req]/p6.  That's 23.2.5 in N4296.